# negative lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: javascript

i want to get an Website out of a string, so I had writen an RegEx pattern using match()

```
var websiteOutput = string.match(/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi);
```

The Problem now is, the string also contains E-Mail Adresses, but I don't want to match these, so I thought about an negative lookbehind and lookhead for '@', but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Should not match, but match:

```
    test.test@test.com
    test@test.com
```

Hope you can help me,
Greetings TZimon

Answer (score 0):

Instead of over complicating the regex , you can try a simpler approach :

```
if(!/@/gi.test(string)){
    var websiteOutput = string.match(/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi);
}
```

i.e accept only the strings which do not have `@` in them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is one big string, from which I want to extract Informations, so this is sadly no possibility